# Blender Cycles Freestyle Line Breaking

Tags: freestyle

I'm trying to make a short 5 minute toon shaded starship scene with Blender Cycles. The ship(s) in the scene also have a toon outline created by two line sets, one thinner one set to only render on creases and edge marks and one thicker one set to only render on object contours.
It looks good and like the way I want it to be, but when I render an animation (camera flyby) I notice that on some frames certain lines break. You can see that here:
https://youtu.be/czazInaUevc

That looks pretty ugly. Is there any way this can be avoided or at least greatly minimized?
Here's the scene's .blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ceVqcvQTiVrjOe-18zJdUkYJpaEqc1QP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: For the benefit of future users (and to make it more likely people will answer), can you include a screenshot of what you mean instead of a video?

Comment: Not in this case as it is only noticeable (or only happens) in animations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to adjust your model (topology) to be better compatible with freestyle.

Two problem of your geometry are

- [intersections](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/introduction.html#known-limitations)
- very sharp angles

[image: intersections and sharp angles]
<sup>*left: intersections; right:sharp angles*</sup>

Freestyle isn't designed to work with intersections. An intersection will remove other lines if freestyle wrongly thinks that a line segment is occluded (even though it may be only partially occluded).

[image: occluded parts]

If you are using *Smooth Shading* and *Subsurf Modifiers*, you should consider checking **Face Smoothness**. The [manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/freestyle/view_map.html#view-maps) is quite vague

> When enabled, Smooth Shading will be taken into account for edges calculation.

However, I have found that some edges with wouldn't be connected, are connected with **Face Smoothness** enabled.

[image: face smoothness]