# Outline using freestyle missing some parts of the mesh

Tags: freestyle

I use freestyle to add outline but somehow the hair line takes over the face.
And the face seems behind the hair.
No not just the hair its also behind the neck.
Like somehow face mesh doesnt exist :|
[image]

Please help me fix this
I dont know where I was wrong :<
Thank you

Comment: check only the option "External Contour"

Comment: Are there some possible [intersections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137423/30849) of your geometry?

Comment: I have check the face mesh a few time to make sure I connected the neck with the face to 1 mesh and no intersection, and I also tried creating another 1 looks like the model im doing
lol it didnt get this problem
I can build the new one but I really want to know wat wrong with the current so I can reslove it next time 
Welp It saves time too

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys
Thanks for ur concern
Its my fault from the first place 
I used solidify modifier to test the out line and some how flipped the face
and well... accidentally clicked apply